# Sharepoint Powershell with CAML<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr>

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, caml

I've was trying to solve this error looking other posts, but i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

In a powershell of Sharepoint 2010 i want to delete all items of a list using the next CAML Query.

```
$query.Query = @'
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Mes"/>
        <Value Type="Text">2017/01</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
    '@

$items = $list.GetItems($query)
$items
```

This give me the following error

```
Excepción al intentar enumerar la colección "<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>".
En línea: 1 Carácter: 7
+ $items <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator
```

[Mes] is a calculated column with text output.

I'm sure i'm doing it wrong. Can you help me please?

Comment: A guess: maybe `Mes` field type isn't `text`? The query should match it. `0x80070057` stands for STRSAFE_E_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Comment: Are you sure `Mes` is the correct internal name of the column? If you sort or filter by that column in the list view, you should see the internal name of the column as a parameter value in the URL query string.

Comment: I'm sure. This is part of the url when mouse over on list setting's field.
`http://server/_layouts/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B...%7D&Field=Mes`

Comment: Can we see the portion of your script where you define the `$query` object? Just want to make sure we're not missing something subtle outside the posted code.